# Using Windows Azure Mobile Services without an account

Tags: android, windows, mobile, azure, service

I have to do a simple app in Android that take pictures and store them in the cloud using Windows Azure Mobile Services. Is there a way to use these services in local, without registering an account, like the azure storage emulator? If no, is there an alternative way that help me to realize and test my app?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want to do, there really isn't a way to do everything locally.  You can sign up for a free account at http://azure.com.